# Get XML attribute value of property using XPath

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have a XML like the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="test" tests="1" time="2.747">
  <properties>
    <property name="categories" value="ExampleCategory" />
    <property name="timestamp" value="1519664414463" />
  </properties>
  <testcase classname="com.example.junit.Test" name="test" time="2.747" />
</testsuite>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the property tag value according to the name of the property?

Right now, I'm using something like that:

```
@doc.xpath('//testsuite//properties//property/@value').text
```

This will give me "ExampleCategory1519664414463". 
I know if I use `.first` or `[0]`, `[1]`, etc, I can get the values separately, but I couldn't find a way to get the values separately according to the "name" attribute.

Anyone know how can I retrieve that?

Comment: Please share the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//property[@name='timestamp']/@value
```

will select all `value` attributes of `property` elements with a `name` attribute value equal to `'timestamp'`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.